# 'yake' is not a package How to resolve the warning message

Tags: python, module, keyword-extraction

I'm trying to use yake in a Windows environment, but a warning appears that yake cannot be used even though I ran pip install yake. Do you know why?

https://github.com/LIAAD/yake
I tried reinstalling, but the same problem still occurs.

can you help i?

Comment: It might be worth trying to install it directly from source with `pip install git+https://github.com/LIAAD/yake`, which is the method they recommend in their README. The version on PyPI hasn't been updated in years and may not work with newer python versions.